# Iterate ArrayList over XML Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I am iterating an arraylist over xml and creating another xml with the list of values present in arraylist. Here is the code am using

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
def books='''
    <response version-api="2.0">
        <value>
            <a>2</a>
            <b>3</b> 
            <e>4</e> 
       </value>
    </response>'''
def lst=["a","b","c","d"]

def sw = new StringWriter()
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(sw)
xml.langs {
    for(String str: lst) {
        def response = new XmlSlurper().parseText(books)

        response.value.'*'.find{ node->        
            if(node.name() == str) {
                "${str}"(node)
            }       
        }
    }
}
println sw
```

This code is working fine for the xml which does not have child nodes How to get all the child nodes of a parent which is present in the arraylist. For example if my list and input has the following

```
lst=["a","b","c","d"]

def books='''
    <response version-api="2.0">
        <value>
            <a>2</a>
            <b>
                <e>4</e> 
            </b>
            <g>123</g>
       </value>
    </response>'''
```

Since a and b are present in the list and node e is a part of b and g is not present in the list, the corresponding xml output should be

```
 <response version-api="2.0">
     <value>
         <a>2</a>
         <b>
             <e>4</e> 
         </b>
     </value>
 </response>'''
```

Comment: you want to remove node `g`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in this case, the transformed xml is almost same as input, except that node `g` is not present in the ouput. Using `XmlParser` to transform.

Here is the script which removes the particular node(all appearances).

**Groovy Script**

```
import groovy.xml.*
def books='''
    <response version-api="2.0">
        <value>
            <a>2</a>
            <b>
                <e>4</e> 
            </b>
            <g>123</g>
       </value>
    </response>'''
def elementsToBeRemoved = ['g'] 
def xml=new XmlParser().parseText(books) 
//Get all the nodes to be removed
def nodes = xml.'**'.findAll{ elementsToBeRemoved.contains(it.name())} 
//Remove all the nodes
nodes.each{it.parent().remove(it)} 
//Serialize to string
XmlUtil.serialize(xml).toString()
```

**EDIT:**

If the xml has `namespaces`, the following change is required.

**Change from:**
`def nodes = xml.'**'.findAll{ it.name() == 'g' }`

**To:**
`def nodes = xml.'**'.findAll{ it.name().localPart == 'g' }`

[image]

**UPDATE2:**

If you want with list of nodes to keep, then here is the simple change needed

```
def elementsToKeep = ["a","b","c","d"]
def nodes = xml.'**'.findAll{ !elementsToKeep.contains(it.name())}
```

Comment: @GroovyBeginner, you gave the input and output in your question and the above is resolving the issue. Isn't it so? If yes, then can you edit the question and make the data input / ouput changes to support your comment?

Comment: @GroovyBeginner, it would be simple to put the unwanted elements in the list, so just put `g` in the list.

Comment: Thank you. This also gives the expected output in much easier way!

Comment: @GroovyBeginner, Also added the otherway as well in `UPDATE 2`.

Comment: The Update 2 is not working as the code is throwing an exception 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method remove() on null object

Comment: @GroovyBeginner, it is clear that you aren't passing null and data specific. Please handle null.

Comment: I have tried the same example with update 2 but it is throwing an exception. The same example is working with update 1

Comment: it is difficult to say without seeing the data.

Comment: I have used the data that you have provided in the answer for update 1